# Android source error reading file from sdcard

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-source

I'm modifying the Android source (AOSP) to create a file `/sdcard/myfile`. The file is created properly and is visible when I do a `cat /sdcard/myfile` from `adb shell`. (The file is created from `PackageManagerService` which is part of the application framework layer)

However, when I try to access the file through code using `new FileReader(myfile)` from the same package manager service code, I get the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/myfile (Permission denied)
```

The permissions on my file are this:

```
----rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw      344 2013-03-15 08:39 myfile
```

What might I be doing wrong? I've checked that the filename is correct by logging the filename I'm trying to access and `cat`ing it.

**Update**:

Here's the complete stack trace:

```
W/System.err(   67): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/myfile (Permission denied)
W/System.err(   67):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
W/System.err(   67):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
W/System.err(   67):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
W/System.err(   67):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:132)
W/System.err(   67):    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
W/System.err(   67):    at org.csrdu.apex.policy.ApexPackagePolicy.getPolicyReader(ApexPackagePolicy.java:224)
W/System.err(   67):    at org.csrdu.apex.policy.ApexPackagePolicy.loadPoliciesForPackage(ApexPackagePolicy.java:82)
W/System.err(   67):    at org.csrdu.apex.AccessManager.checkExtendedPermissionByPackage(AccessManager.java:56)
W/System.err(   67):    at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.checkUidPermission(PackageManagerService.java:1703)
W/System.err(   67):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkComponentPermission(ActivityManagerService.java:4096)
W/System.err(   67):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:1960)
W/System.err(   67):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:2516)
W/System.err(   67):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:2081)
W/System.err(   67):    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:142)
W/System.err(   67):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1467)
W/System.err(   67):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
W/System.err(   67):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check your sdcare mounted or unmounted???

Comment: please provide the error log and code if possible

Comment: @altaf, yes it is. I can access it with `adb shell` properly. 
@cwhsu Provided the log but I think only the first line is relevant. :(

Comment: You may need <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>" in your manifest.

Comment: @HoanNguyen, I'm in the source and this is a system service so I don't think permissions apply here. I wouldn't know where to put them since there is no Manifest file for `PackageManagerService`.

Comment: didn't notice that you're modifying a system service...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why adb shell can access it while PackageManagerService cannot?**

The PackageManagerService runs with the user `system`. And it it not run in the group sdcard_rw. So according to the permissions your provide, a permission denial encountered. However, adb shell could access it, because adb shell using the user `shell`, which has been granted the permission to access sdcard(within sdcard_rw group).

```
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
</permission>
<assign-permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" uid="shell" />
```

**Why PackageManagerService runs with the user system?**

PackageManagerService is started in the init2 method of SystemServer.java.

```
pm = PackageManagerService.main(context,
                factoryTest != SystemServer.FACTORY_TEST_OFF);
```

The SystemServer is started by ZygoteInit.java.

```
    String args[] = {
        "--setuid=1000",
        "--setgid=1000",
        "--setgroups=1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,3001,3002,3003",
        "--capabilities=130104352,130104352",
        "--runtime-init",
        "--nice-name=system_server",
        "com.android.server.SystemServer",
    };
    ....
    /* Request to fork the system server process */
    pid = Zygote.forkSystemServer(
                parsedArgs.uid, parsedArgs.gid,
                parsedArgs.gids, debugFlags, null,
                parsedArgs.permittedCapabilities,
                parsedArgs.effectiveCapabilities);
```

And check what those uid values mean in android_filesystem_config.h:

```
#define AID_ROOT             0  /* traditional unix root user */

#define AID_SYSTEM        1000  /* system server */

#define AID_RADIO         1001  /* telephony subsystem, RIL */
#define AID_BLUETOOTH     1002  /* bluetooth subsystem */
#define AID_GRAPHICS      1003  /* graphics devices */
#define AID_INPUT         1004  /* input devices */
#define AID_AUDIO         1005  /* audio devices */
#define AID_CAMERA        1006  /* camera devices */
#define AID_LOG           1007  /* log devices */
#define AID_COMPASS       1008  /* compass device */
#define AID_MOUNT         1009  /* mountd socket */
#define AID_WIFI          1010  /* wifi subsystem */
#define AID_ADB           1011  /* android debug bridge (adbd) */
#define AID_INSTALL       1012  /* group for installing packages */
#define AID_MEDIA         1013  /* mediaserver process */
#define AID_DHCP          1014  /* dhcp client */
#define AID_SDCARD_RW     1015  /* external storage write access */
```

So system server run with user `system`, without sdcard_rw group, so does PackageManagerService.

**Why still permission deny after add system to sdcard_rw group?**

I create a file on Linux:

```
----rw---- 1 jermaine developers 0 Mar 12 23:01 a
```

So user in developers group can rw it.

And I add jermaine into the developers group by:

```
usermod -a -G develoeprs jermaine
```

However, the user `jermaine` can still not access that file. Linux will deny the access from owner in this case without checking the group.

**How to fix?**

chmod after your create that file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's very illuminating. However, I added the `assign-permission` to `system` in `/frameworks/base/data/etc/platform.xml` but still get the same problem. `cat platform.xml` shows that the permission is indeed present but no cake. :(

Comment: Sorry, I realize that the assign-permission is used by PackageManager itself. So it won't work. Can you please try add 1015 to --setgroups=1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,3001,3002,3003 in ZygoteInit.java.  @recluze

Comment: Already trying that as you suggested (2) before. Thanks :) .. will post if it works.

Comment: About your last update on how I'm creating it: I just realized that because I was getting errors, I moved the file creation out to an app. So, the file is being created in the app which is satisfied by your theory/description perfectly.

Comment: The file is created in an app, why its owner is system? @recluze

Comment: Hnn, didn't notice that. I don't know why that happened. I didn't change owner or anything though. The app is PackageInstaller and that probably runs as `system` I think.

Comment: Well, it just compiled and I ran it after adding 1015 to groups but still the same permission denied.

Comment: Have you checked is the AID_SDCARD_RW is still 1015 in your Android version in android_filesystem_config.h?

Comment: I just tested on a linux system, I create a file in mode 064, with myusername:mygroupname, and add my username into the groupname by usermod, and it fails to rw the file anyway. So I think the problem is linux will deny the access from the owner if the file cannot rw by its owner regardless of checking the group. @recluze

Comment: Hnn, I tried `chmod` during file write but it returns `false` and doesn't change the permissions. I think I might be asking the wrong question. I will mark this as accepted since it answers the question in detail but can you please look at the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426802/write-meta-information-during-android-package-install and see if you can answer it.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at it soon. @recluze

Comment: Still curious about how you can create a file with the owner "system" in an app. It is the key to this question I think.

Comment: I don't know about that. I `make clean`ed everything, and simply did a `PrinterWriter` output to a file in `/sdcard`. It came out as `system:sdcard_rw`