# Write meta information during Android package install

Tags: android, android-source

**Question:** How to write meta information about a package OR Where is the installation intent handled in `PackageManagerService` in android source? (Description follows.)

I'm modifying Android source to save some meta information about a package during installation. It can be stored in any location but has to be readable by the system. My first attempt was to use `/sdcard` ([Android source error reading file from sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424603/android-source-error-reading-file-from-sdcard/15424662?noredirect=1)) But that does not seem to work because of permissions.

Now, I want to be able to send the meta information to the `PackageManagerService` so that it can write it before install. If it writes it itself, it should be able to read it later.

I've identified the point in `PackageInstallerActivity`, the place where the installation intent is raised:

```
if(v == mOk) {
            // Start subactivity to actually install the application
            Intent newIntent = new Intent();
            newIntent.putExtra(PackageUtil.INTENT_ATTR_APPLICATION_INFO,
                    mPkgInfo.applicationInfo);
            newIntent.setData(mPackageURI);
            newIntent.setClass(this, InstallAppProgress.class);
            String installerPackageName = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME);
            if (installerPackageName != null) {
                newIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME, installerPackageName);
            }
            if(localLOGV) Log.i(TAG, "downloaded app uri="+mPackageURI);
```

I can put an "extra" in the intent but I don't know where in the PackageManagerService this intent is handled.

**So, the qustion:** Where is the installation intent handled in PackageManagerService in android source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see, the intent is an explicit intent with a component: `InstallAppProgress.class`.

So that intent will be handled first by InstallAppProgress. It is also a component in PackageInstaller. It is responsible for displaying the installation progress(initView() in InstallAppProgress.java). And in the initView() method, it will call PackageManagerService:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mAppInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(PackageUtil.INTENT_ATTR_APPLICATION_INFO);
    mPackageURI = intent.getData();
    initView();
}

public void initView() {
    ...
    String installerPackageName = getIntent().getStringExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME);
    PackageInstallObserver observer = new PackageInstallObserver();
    pm.installPackage(mPackageURI, observer, installFlags, installerPackageName);
}
```

So the intent is not handled by PackageManagerService, it is handled by the InstallAppProgress, then it simply call PackageManagerService to install that app.

I used to working on a partial permission granting system on Android. What I did is to add an argument to installPackage method in PMS, so I think you can do it like that, too. PackageManager is an aidl service, so you also need to modify the aidl file too. It is under `framework/base/core/java/android/content/pm/`

Comment: Thanks. I did explore this earlier but I think I called the function earlier than the inter-process jump so got a permission denied. Trying again now to see how it goes. Will post update here.

Comment: Perfect. Finally got it to work. The inter-process jump was required which you hinted to with AIDL. Thanks again.